# Botão de rolar do mouse em um relatório do quick report

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, quickreport

Como fazer o botão de rolagem do mouse funcionar em relatórios do Quick Report.

Hoje utilizo um Preview personalizado usando o componente TQRPreview.

Utilizo o Delphi 7 e o Quick Report 3.0.9.

Answer (score 2):

### **Atualizado 05/07/2016**

Encontrei essa outra dica no fórum da Embarcadero, até mais simples que a dica abaixo.

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
var Handled: Boolean);
var
    i: SmallInt;
    pt : Tpoint;
begin
    GetCursorPos(pt); // Get the position from Cursor
    if Msg.message = WM_MOUSEWHEEL then // WheelMouse Message when scrolling
    begin 
        Msg.lParam := 0;
        i := HiWord(Msg.wParam) ;
        if i > 0 then // If Scrolling Up
            SendMessage(WindowFromPoint(pt),WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP,0) 
        else 
            SendMessage(WindowFromPoint(pt),WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN,0);

        Handled := False;
    end;
end;
```

1. Drope um componente **Application Event** no seu formulário.
2. Vá na aba de eventos e adicione o `OnMessage`
3. Copie e cole o código acima no evento adicionado.

---

**Segunda dica mais antiga**

Primeiro, adicione um evento `BeforePrint` no seu relatório:

```
procedure Form1.QuickRep1BeforePrint(Sender: TCustomQuickRep;
  var PrintReport: Boolean);
begin
  SetupMouseWheel;
end;
```

Depois, crie a função `SetupMouseWheel`:

```
procedure Form1.SetupMouseWheel;
begin
  with TQRStandardPreview(Application.FindComponent('QRStandardPreview')) do
    begin
      OnMouseWheel := MouseWheel;
    end;
end;
```

Por fim, crie a função `MouseWheel`:

```
procedure Form1.MouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  with TQRStandardPreview(Application.FindComponent('QRStandardPreview')) do
  begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    VertScrollBar.Range := 1350;
    VertScrollBar.Position := VertScrollBar.Position - trunc(WheelDelta / 4);
  end;
end;
```

**Substitua o `QRStandardPreview` nas duas funções pelo nome do seu componente `TQRPreview`.**

---

**Veja mais aqui:**

[QuickReport Delphi 7 - Rolagem na barra de rolagem.](http://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/delphi-quickreport/1303551/)

Comment: você tem algum exemplo que possa me enviar. Fiz como está no seu exemplo e não deu certo. Nesta parte do código "OnMouseWheel := MouseWheel;", da access violation.

Comment: Olá Ariel, você substituiu o `QRStandardPreview` pelo nome do seu componente? Pode ser nesta parte que ele dá o erro de memória, pois não existe o componente. Verifique novamente o post, eu adicionei uma atualização com um código que encontrei no site da Embarcadero.

Comment: Olá Vitor, para resolver está situação, fiz desta forma. No evento onMouseWheel coloquei o seguinte código:

Application.ProcessMessages;
QRPreview.VertScrollBar.Position := QRPreview.VertScrollBar.Position - trunc(WheelDelta / 4);

Isso já foi o bastante para que o que estava precisando funcionasse.

Comment: Ariel, sim também dá certo, a diferença é que você acessou o componente diretamente sem buscar ele como eu fiz no exemplo. Teste também com o **ApplicationEvents** que eu coloquei acima, ele manda uma mensagem de scroll para o seu relatório, talvez seja até mais simples.